# pixel recognize in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, pixel, ccsprite

How to recognize the presence of a color pixel and no color pixels?
I have  two sprites, 1 ball and the second sprite is a map, if no color then the ball just flies and all, but as soon as there is a color burst.

In particular I want to recognize the region where no color is, but do it all the time. How can I implement this in cocos2d?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this post on the cocos2d forum. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2449
Hope it helps!